# How to mount Android 10 vendor image file

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, android, ext4

I used to extract Android vendor image via following steps:

1. Convert sparse image to raw image: `simg2img vendor.img v.img`
2. Mount the raw image for copying files: `sudo mount v.img somefolder`

However, when I try to do this on Android 10 vendor images (like [this one](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/google_devices-sargo-qp1a.190711.020-84e6fe8a.tgz) from Google factory images), I always failed at 2nd step:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop16, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

And the dmesg shows the following error:

```
EXT4-fs (loop16): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (4000)
```

I searched for these information online and got some potential solution like this one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287159/linux-couldnt-mount-rdwr-because-of-unsupported-optional-features-400/454918#454918?newreg=968857b0b61a41c799539cace57251ca), but it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how can I mount and the new Android vendor image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to 'READ' the image contents:

```
sudo mount -o ro v.img somefolder
```

where "v.img" is your unsparsed ext4 image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reminding, I should have thought of it:)

Comment: what if you need to mount, add files and repack the image?

Comment: how do you mount read-write?