# How to mount Android 10 vendor image file / how to mount ext4 .img in write mode?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, android, ext4

I'm getting the exact same error as [How to mount Android 10 vendor image file](https://superuser.com/questions/1480431/how-to-mount-android-10-vendor-image-file), that is, when I decompressed `system.new.dat.br` from an Android ROM to a `system.img` and when I try to mount with:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop unpacked_system.img system
```

I get on dmesg:

```
[ 1589.045816] EXT4-fs (loop2): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (4000)
```

I tried mounting as read only and it worked:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o ro unpacked_system.img system/
```

but I want to repack this img, that is, modify some contents. I could copy the files to a new folder and repack into a new .img, but I think there should be a better way. What can I do to mount a ext4 .img in write mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount system under super partion?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221947/how-to-mount-system-under-super-partion)

Comment: `e2fsck -E unshare_blocks`